# Angular 9 - GET request parses string into wrong value

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, urlencode

I am trying to send a simple string as Queryparameter with a GET request in Angular 9.
The string contains special chars like +

by example

```
  getString(stringParam: string): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('api param', stringParam);
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('stringParam', stringParam);
    return this.http.get<boolean>(`${URL}/param`, { params });
  }
```

the console log shows me **PL + QP/2** but the query param is send like **PL QP/2** in the headers.

So for some reason it drops the + (and probably some other chars also, not confirmed)
And I got no clue why, does anyone has a lead on this? I tried playing with the URI encoding, but I did not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like angular still having problems with that. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `+` character by percent-encoding it with `encodeUriComponent()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

The `+` character is a reserved character and is ofted used to replace spaces in a url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Here's an example comparing the two: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kbs-so-ng-reserved-character-url?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Debugging that character can be tricky because once removed some browsers will show a space as `+` character leading you to believe it's present when it's not in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, after some extra debugging I noticed that the URIComponent is not necessary, the param is encoded correctly without. BUT I noticed that the request URL was double encoded, Im still figuring that out.